# Install minimal xfce4 system wide, as default

Tags: xfce, desktop-environment

I have a minimal installation of Ubuntu 16.04 on a machine. I want to add the XFCE4 desktop environment, without all the craptastic bloat that comes standard with `xubuntu-desktop`. When I boot, I would like to be greeted by a graphical login screen. Thus far I have tried (and failed spectacularly!) with:

- Installing `xfce4` package and setting default runlevel to graphical.target. Result - reboots to terminal
- Installing `xfce4-session` and setting default runlevel to graphical.target. Result - reboots to graphical login, but always gives a "Failed to start session" error when attempting to login.
- Installed `xfce4`, `xfce4-session`, and `lightdm` while setting default runlevel to graphical.target. Result - reboots to terminal.

At this point I'm getting a little irritated, I want this to be an automagical thing, not one where I or my user has to type `startxfce4` command every time we turn the computer on.